# Write this formula in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I would like some help, to find out how I would be able to write the below formula in VBA;

```
=IF((COLUMNS($G13:G13)<=$F13),INDEX(DateHeadings,,SMALL(IF(TableBodyRow="E",COLUMN(DateHeadings)-4+1),COLUMNS($G13:G13))),"")
```

I can use the excel formula as is, but unfortunately when the named range "TableBodyRow" is used it creates an absolute reference when I need a relative one. Unless there is a solution to change that without having to go back into "Name Manager".

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want the dumb answer here it is. Copy your formulas to your clipboard then run record macro. Select a cell and paste the formula from the clipboard into it. End record macro, and now you have your answer.